# Easiest way to edit company e-mail signatures

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange

I was given a task of adding a specific line item into everyone's e-mail signature, but trying to find the easiest way of doing so. This particular item I am to add is an image/link to our employer's facebook page. I was hoping I could do something through Active Directory, but not sure how that would all work.

I'm not very good at script writing either, and the only other way I know to manage a signature is actually going into Outlook's options and doing so from there. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your company is using an Exchange server and Active Directory Domain Controller then I would recommend to standardize the email signatures via Group Policies. This will not only allow you to make this change *instantaneously** to current users, but will also take into effect for any new users of your company.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924617

*a refresh of the Group Policies would be required. This can be done server side but will require users' computer to be logged in. However, next time they log in while connected to the ADDC, it should refresh the policies.